# What will be the value of static variable flag?

Tags: java

```
public class A{
    private static flag;

    public void count(){
        flag++;
    }
}

public class B extends A{
    public void count(){
        super.count();
    }
}

public class C extends A{
    public void count(){
        super.count();
    }
}

}

public class D extends A{
    public void count(){
        super.count();
    }
}
```

Lets us suppose my classes are executed in the following manner
class B
Class C
class D

Now i want to know that what will be the value of flag instance variable
after Class D count method

Comment: why don't you try it yourself and check the value ?

Comment: why not just executing it and printing?

Comment: It has no value, as the code doesn't compile.

Comment: -1 as this really isn't constructive at all.

Comment: Go and Study and try it your self......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tldr; a "static field" or "class variable" represents a [single variable shared among all instances](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html) of a class (including subclasses):

> Sometimes, you want to have variables that are common to all objects. This is accomplished with the static modifier. Fields that have the static modifier in their declaration are called static fields or class variables. *They [static fields] are associated with the class, rather than with any object. **Every instance of the class shares a class variable, which is in one fixed location in memory.*** Any object can change the value of a class variable, but class variables can also be manipulated without creating an instance of the class.

There is only *one* variable with that particular name. In this case the class qualified name is `A.flag` (prepending the package would make it fully qualified). Java just allows static fields be accessed in an instance-qualified manner, which I would consider a historical mistake .. as static fields exist independent of any instance.

Comment: +1 for pointing out historical mistakes.

Answer (score 2):

You would be simply calling flag++ three times. So the final value would be flag+3 (You have to initialize flag). You have to take care of concurrency issues though.

Answer (score 1):

It's static, so however many times you call it, that's what the value will be if all you're doing is incrementing it each time no matter which class you call it from.

Not sure if that's the question or not.

Comment: I want to know that if i am extending the class that should it be compiled again or not?

Comment: i am talking about extending class.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you correct the declaration:

```
private static int flag;
```

...until/unless someone actually creates an instance of `A`, `B`, `C`, or `D`, `flag` is `0` because that's the value it gets at initialization.

If you start instantiating things and calling their `count` function (you have to instantiate them to do that, as `count` is not `static`), its value will be increased by the code in `A#count`. Because it's a `static`, the same member is shared across instances. Thus:

```
new A().count();
// Now it's 1
new B().count();
// Now it's 2
```

Etc.